# get() returned more than one OrderProduct -- it returned 3

Tags: python, django

My error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /process/
get() returned more than one OrderProduct -- it returned 3!

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/process/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned

Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one OrderProduct -- it returned 3!
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 499, in get

Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.4

Python Path:    
['D:\\Online_Shop_Django',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 26 May 2022 16:57:38 +0500
```

My views:

```
 if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    del session['cart']
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_product, created = OrderProduct.objects.get_or_create(
        order=order, )
    order.save()
messages.success(request, 'Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!')
return redirect('product_list')
```

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what `OrderProduct` is for. There may be an underlying data model issue you need to remedy. For the purpose of this I will address only the django related concerns.

### Use `.filter().first()`

[`.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) + [`.first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#first) can be used for control flow instead of [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get).

```py
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    del session["cart"]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    order_product = OrderProduct.objects.filter(order=order).first()

    if order_product is None:
        order_product = OrderProduct(order=order)
        order_product.save()
    order.save()
messages.success(request, "Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!")
return redirect("product_list")
```

### `.get_or_create()` / `.get()`: Error handling

[`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) is simply a wrapper for [`.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get).

[`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/class/#django.db.models.Model.MultipleObjectsReturned) is an [exception you can handle](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) via [`try`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) / `except`.

```py
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    session = request.session
    cart = session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
    del session["cart"]
else:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    try:
        order_product, created = OrderProduct.objects.get_or_create(order=order)
    except OrderProduct.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        # You would need to decide what you want to do here
        print(f'Multiple objects returned for {order}')
    order.save()
messages.success(request, "Заказ успешно оформлен. Проверьте свою электронную почту!!!")
return redirect("product_list")
```

Comment: @Saidcheek There isn't enough information for me to know that. You may need to make a new question. But, you can try to [`.pop()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.pop) after `order.save()`, `request.session.pop(settings.CART_SESSION_ID, None)` or `request.session.pop('cart', None)`. Not sure where your cart session is stored. Be careful about that though since I'm not sure